# Form is not responding but timer is still running

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, windows-7

I have created [a video](http://youtu.be/_zTLy_xY_uw) which explains my problem. In text form - My Main form is crashing when the timer is run and i'm not sure why, the application keeps running, even though the main form seems to have crashed.

```
namespace ItunesGamesEqualiser
{
    public partial class GUI : Form
    {
        private void refreshBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = prbLevel.Value;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AudioSessionControl session;
            AudioSessionControl itunesSession;
            MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            MMDevice device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
            // Note the AudioSession manager did not have a method to enumerate all sessions in windows Vista
            // this will only work on Win7 and newer.
            for (int i = 0; i < device.AudioSessionManager.Sessions.Count; i++)
            {
                itunesSession = device.AudioSessionManager.Sessions[i];

                if (itunesSession.SessionIdentifier.Contains("iTunes") == true) //find itunes audio service
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < device.AudioSessionManager.Sessions.Count; j++)
                    {
                        session = device.AudioSessionManager.Sessions[j];
                        if (session.SessionIdentifier.Contains("iTunes") == false) //find game audio service
                        {

                            if (session.State == AudioSessionState.AudioSessionStateActive)
                            {
                                Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)session.ProcessID);
                                Console.WriteLine("ProcessName: {0}", p.ProcessName);
                                AudioMeterInformation mi = session.AudioMeterInformation;
                                AudioMeterInformation imi = itunesSession.AudioMeterInformation;
                                SimpleAudioVolume vol = session.SimpleAudioVolume;
                                SimpleAudioVolume ivol = itunesSession.SimpleAudioVolume;
                                //int start = Console.CursorTop;
                                ivol.MasterVolume = 1;
                                float origVol = ivol.MasterVolume;
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    //Draw a VU meter
                                    int len = (int)(mi.MasterPeakValue * 79);
                                    int ilen = (int)(imi.MasterPeakValue * 79);
                                    //Console.SetCursorPosition(0, start);
                                    //Game Meter
                                    if (len > 30)
                                    {
                                        float curvol = origVol - (0.1f * (len - 10) / 10);
                                        if (curvol < 0) curvol = 0;
                                        ivol.MasterVolume = curvol;
                                        prbLevel.Value = len;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ivol.MasterVolume = origVol;
                                        //Console.WriteLine("null");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //If we end up here there where no open audio sessions to monitor.
            lblName.Text = "No game found, please start game and iTunes";
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I´m wrong, but if the form crashes and the app continues running, it might be because you are using only one thread. Try using one thread when you start timer1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application crashes because of your code in timer tick event. App continues running even after crashing because the timer is not disabled or disposed. Timer class requests GC not to collect using - GCHandle.Alloc, when you set timer.Enabled = true. So even after timer object reference goes not-reachable it will not be garbage collected. Fix the problem in your timer tick event and dipose the timer properly.